# Count the number of specific words in file using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a file in which contents are in following order:

```
This is not right
Right statement it is
This is incorrect
Give right expression
```

How do I find the count of the word 'right' using tcl script? Since it is not in list I’m unable to uniquify these statements and take the expression.
Which commands are proper to use lsort or regexp?

Comment: This is not right Right statement \n   it is This is incorrect \n     Give right expression\n

Comment: \n means next line i.e I have these 5 lines with words 'right' in them and I want to search for repeated words and their count

Comment: Also I need to know another word "this" . I want to have o/p as below:                                             right : 5  and this : 3

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the text is in the file "myfile.txt", we can copy the text into the `text` variable:

```
set f [open myfile.txt]
set text [read $f]
# => This is not right
# => Right statement it is
# => This is incorrect
# => Give right expression
close $f
```

An inline search for all matches ignoring case gives a list of words which we can count:

```
llength [regexp -inline -all -nocase right $text]
# => 3
llength [regexp -inline -all -nocase this $text]
# => 2
```

(Which is correct: there are three "right" and two "this" in the text.)

This will do the same job as we're not actually interested in the list of words, just the number of words:

```
regexp -all -nocase this $text
```

These simple regular expressions work when none of the words occur inside other words, such as "right" in "bright" or "this" in "empathise". If such false positives are possible, the regular expression needs to be more sophisticated. `\m` and `\M` constraints can be used to mark the beginning and the end of a word, respectively:

```
regexp -all -nocase {\mright\M} $text
```

This will match "right" but not "bright" or "sprightly".

Another way to calculate the frequency of every word in the text is to use a dictionary structure:

```
set words {}
foreach word [split [string tolower $text]] {
    dict incr words $word
}
```

Now, we can query the structure for the frequency of individual words:

```
dict get $words right
# => 3
dict get $words this
# => 2
```

Or take a look at the frequency table:

```
set words
# => this 2 is 3 not 1 right 3 statement 1 it 1 incorrect 1 give 1 expression 1
```

**update** word frequency for last words in sentence.

You wrote "statement", but I presume you mean "sentence". If this is wrong, you need to tell me how to recognize the end of a statement.

Defining a word at the end of a sentence as a sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by a literal period character, the frequence of those words can be calculated like this:

```
set words {}
foreach word [regexp -inline -all {\S+(?=\.)} [string tolower $text]] {
    dict incr words $word
}
```

And then proceeding as above.

Documentation:
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: I got answer as 0.

Comment: @johnny: I have tested it now, and it works for me. Did you put your text in the text variable?

Comment: You can use `regexp -all` to just count the number of matches. Also, what's supposed to happen when faced with the phrase `Jonny Mathis is frightfully good.`?

Comment: @Peter Lewerin : it works fine now but my question was a more generic one. I have different repeating words and over a thousand lines in my file. My aim is to find out repeating words and I dont know the exact number of count. Is it possible to find out all those words which keep repeating and their count: For example I want all words at the end of statement and their count

Comment: @johnny: there is no fully generic solution. The three solutions I've presented so far (including the one in the update) solve the problem under different constraints (the word is known, every word is to be counted, only words at the end or a sentence is to be counted). Every time the problem description changes, the solution needs to change as well. Maybe you can extrapolate from the examples given here?

Comment: @johnny: also, you don't need to @-tag me when commenting my answer, I get notified anyway.

Comment: I have another issue:
I have set all end elements to a variable x. Now my variable x contains following:
right
right
right
this
this

I used your command : llength [regexp -inline -all -nocase right $x]
and I got result as 1. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: You put it as set x [right right right]

Whereas my code is not as a string but as lines
right  \n
right \n

Comment: 3 lines with "right" word and 2 lines with "this" word all in a file.
I need to get o/p as :
right = 3
this = 2

Comment: @johnny: I can't reproduce this either: setting `x` with `set x {right right right this this}`, `llength [regexp -inline -all -nocase right $x]` returns 3. (Newlines in the value of `x` don't matter here.)

Comment: I am still getting the o/p as 1 only. My variable x contains all these lines . How can I convert them to a list?

Comment: @johnny: you can convert a string to a list with e.g. `split`. You shouldn't do that here, though, since `regexp` expects a string. (Strings and lists are mostly interchangeable in Tcl, but let's not go into that now.) What does `regexp -inline -all -nocase right $x` return?

Comment: @johnny Do you get `right \n right \n` etc when you do `puts $x`? It might be an issue with your file and the eof char. I've had this before.